# Referencing a variable when getting object value

Tags: javascript

If I have a function like this:

```
var get = function(place, info){
    return places.place.info;
}
```

and JSON like this:

```
var places = {
    "london":{
        "distance":50,
        "time":100
    }
}
```

How can I make the function get return the correct value if I use the following? At the moment it's taking it completely literally:

```
get("london", "time");
```

Comment: What does "taking it completely literally" mean?

Comment: FYI, `places` is a JavaScript object, not JSON. JSON is a textual data exchange format, like XML, YAML, CSV, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should use square brackets notation:

```
var get = function(place, info){
    return places[place][info];
};
```

I'd also add some fool proof check, e.g.:

```
var get = function(place, info){
    return places[place] !== undefined
        && places[place][info];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use square bracket syntax:

`places[place][info]`